# Couldn't locate provisioning file from Xcode's "Download Manual Profile"

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, xcode14

I'm new to this and using a free developer account and was trying to download manual profile from Xcode (I'm using Xcode 14), but the folder at `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/` still appears to be empty after doing so.

This are the steps I took. Xcode > Preference > Accounts > Select my Apple ID and Download Manual Profile > Navigate to `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/` using Command + Shift + G on Finder.

I tried restarting the Macbook, deleting and readding my developer account, but none seems to work. Still in search for post with similar problems. Also, could it be that it is a limitation imposed on free accounts? I couldn't find it anywhere that says the free account cannot downlaod manual profiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've located the provisioning profile with the automatic signing. XCode auto-generates the provisioning profile which can be found in the signing and capabilities tab.